# Convert string to parenthesized S-expression in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

How can I convert a string like `"(+ ( - 5 2) 8)"` to an s-expression `(+ (- 5 2) 8)` that can be evaluated in the Racket prompt? I tried `string->symbol` but it returns `'|(+ ( - 5 2) 8)|` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `read` function in racket (or any other lisp) does just this. Except `read` will read from an input port rather than a string. You can use `open-input-string` function for that.

```
(read (open-input-string "(+ (- 5 2))"))
```